# Regex Expression for Hashtags

Tags: ruby, regex

```
/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i
```

This is the current expression i use. It works fine except the dash `-` is not allowed. I need this: `#what-ever` to be captured.

How can i add the `dash` to this expression ?

Comment: seems a bit complicated, you're just searching for a hashtag in a text ?

Comment: Yeap! Hashtag extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the pattern which was present inside the first capturing group that is `\w` plus `-` into a character class. So that it would capture a word character or a `-` symbol. `+` after the character class makes the previous token to repeat one or more times.

```
(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))([-\w]+)(?=\s|$)
                                             |here|
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/8)